# Converting string to array with brace

Tags: php

I try to convert a string containing shedule to an array

For exemple

```
convert("{{09:00,10:00},{18:00,19:00}}") // returns [['09:00','10:00'],['18:00','19:00']]
```

Is there a way more elegant than this one :

```
    function convert($shedules) {
            $shedules = explode('},{', $horaires);
            $shedules = array_map(function ($shedule) {
                return explode(',', str_replace(['{', '}'], '', $shedule));
            }, $shedules);

          return $shedules
    }
```

Comment: How do you get the string?  Can you not get valid JSON with quoted data?

Comment: No I can't it is old data stored in database

Comment: Could you add a few more examples of the data format, so that we know what the constraints are? For instance: is it always exactly 2 pairs of values, or a variable length list of pairs, or completely variable? Are the values always times in HH:MM format, or are there other possibilities? (If you have any unit tests, the samples to show us will be the same ones that make really good test cases. :))

Comment: The values are always HH:MM but it is a variable list of pairs